# Returning to the same part of page (css/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So, here is the code

```js
jQuery('.item').click(function() {  
    jQuery('.popup').show();
    jQuery('.main').hide(); 
}); 

jQuery('.go_back').click(function() {  
    jQuery('.main').show();
    jQuery('.popup').hide(); 
});
```

```css
.box{
   border-style: solid;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   margin: 16px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
.popup_content{
   border-style: solid;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   margin: 16px;
   background-color: #3f51b5;
   color: #fff;
    padding:16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">    
    <div class="item item_1" data-id="item_1">
        <div class="box container_1 ">
            Item 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item_2" data-id="item_2">
        <div class="box container_2">
            Item 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item_3" data-id="item_3">
        <div class="box container_3">
            item 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item_4" data-id="item_4">
        <div class="box container_4">
            Item 4
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item_5" data-id="item_5">
        <div class="box container_5">
            Item 5
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item_6" data-id="item_6">
        <div class="box container_6">
            Item 6
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item_7" data-id="item_7">
        <div class="box container_7">
            Item 7
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item_8" data-id="item_8">
        <div class="box container_8">
            Item 8
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item_9" data-id="item_9">
        <div class="box container_9">
            Item 9
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item_10" data-id="item_10">
        <div class="box container_10">
            Item 10
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="popup" style="display:none;">
    <div class="popup_content">
        Popup content
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="go_back">Go back</button>
</div>
```

Here is the setup.

There are 10 containers in the main div. When one of them is clicked, the `main` div is hidden and "popup" is shown (see the js).

Now, imagine a scenario in which you click "Item 10" box which is located at the bottom of the page. Then the "popup" div will be shown. If you click "Go back" button then you will see the main content again, but now you are at the top of the page, not at "Item 10".

I know why it is scrolled to the top of page (because the `popup` content is shorter in height than the `main` div). Because the `popup` div will never be taller than the `main` div, is there a way to "Go back" to the same section of the main div?

For example, if you click "Item 10", and you see the popup content, then you click "Go back", I want to show "Item 10" instead of "Item 1" (Hope, I am making sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/h62hk07v/

Instead of hiding the `main` div and showing `popup` in its place, you can use CSS fixed positioning to allow the popup to cover up the main div. Then when you hide it, the user's scroll position is preserved. (This is how [Bootstrap's modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) work.)

css

```
.popup {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:white;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:30;
}
```

jquery

```
jQuery('.item').click(function() {      
    jQuery('.popup').show();
}); 

jQuery('.go_back').click(function() {       
    jQuery('.popup').hide();    
});
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. =) Thank you. Simple solution. Learned something new. =)

Answer (score 2):

A JavaScript way of doing this is using a new variable to cache the position of scroll:

https://jsfiddle.net/csj7k4m1/1/

```
var PositionCache = 0;

jQuery('.item').click(function() {
    PositionCache = jQuery('body').scrollTop();
    jQuery('.popup').show();
    jQuery('.main').hide(); 
}); 

jQuery('.go_back').click(function() {
    jQuery('.main').show();
    jQuery('.popup').hide();    
    jQuery('body').scrollTop(PositionCache);
});
```

That way you won't have to make modifications to your layout.

Edit:

This has an arguable advantage over `position: fixed;` as users often scroll the page when the content is on display thus defeating the purpose of returning positions.

Edit 2:

As @Jeremy Swinarton mentioned it is easy to prevent scroll by adding another css property `overflow:hidden;` to the body but the argument still stands as the content behind the modal needs to be rendered. In some cases this is ideal (popup doesn't cover the entire page) but in some cases such as when dealing with low-powered devices and using MVC models it would be ideal (depending on your structure) to render one View at a time thus separating content to provide better performance.

Comment: There are better ways to go about fixing scroll behaviour when modals are open—the best would be to apply `overflow: hidden` on the `body` when the modal is open. Tracking scroll position using `scrollTop` seems like overkill here.

Comment: @JeremySwinarton, I personally use that exact technique (`overflow:hidden`) in most of my projects that's why I used the arguable. Although I found out that using MVC View such as Backbone, it is preferable to store the `scrollTop` position when the content behind the popup/modal (the View in MVC) doesn't need to be rendered by the browser.